# python requests POST cookie session

Tags: python

Folks,
  Trying to learn `requests` module for python... and a simple project to pull any pending parking tickets.

Is this the correct way to save session and cookies between a `GET` and a `POST` request?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import requests
import urllib

session = requests.Session()

tokenRequest = session.get('https://paydirect.link2gov.com/NYCParking-Plate/ItemSearch')
sessionToken = tokenRequest.cookies['__RequestVerificationToken']
sessionCookies = tokenRequest.cookies
sessionHeaders = tokenRequest.headers

payload = {
    '__RequestVerificationToken': sessionToken,
    'ItemSearchQuestionUserInput': 'myplate',
    'Questions[0].IsRequired': 'True',
    'Questions[0].Sequence': 1,
    'Questions[0].Text': 'PlateNumber',
    'Questions[0].Type': 'Text',
    'ItemSearchQuestionUserInput[1].QuestionAnswer': 'NY',
    'Questions[1].IsRequired': 'True',
    'Questions[1].Sequence': 2,
    'Questions[1].Text': 'State',
    'Questions[1].Type': 'Text',
    'Questions[2].IsRequired': 'False',
    'Questions[2].Sequence': 3,
    'Questions[2].Text': 'PlateType',
    'Questions[2].Type': 'Text',
    'SubmitButton': 'Continue'
}
raw = urllib.urlencode(payload)
plateRequest = session.post('https://paydirect.link2gov.com/NYCParking-Plate/ItemSearch/Submit', data=raw, headers=sessionHeaders, cookies=sessionCookies)

print plateRequest.text
```

Does not seem to work...  Im sure its something simple i am missing.  Their website is here: https://paydirect.link2gov.com/NYCParking-Plate/ItemSearch

Thanks!

Comment: and no, they dont have a public API...

Comment: There are two __RequestVerificationToken: first in cookies and second in html-code: '<input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="some_value" /> '. And this token from html should be placed in payload = {
    '__RequestVerificationToken': token_from_html}. But it still did not help :(.

Comment: @NorthCat yes, it sucks.  wish they had a simple rest api.  anyways, where do you think we're making a mistake?

Comment: I honestly do not know. I'll try to experiment tomorrow...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems the server is particular about receiving an explicit `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` header, which `requests` doesn't send by default. Also, it wouldn't accept the value of the `__RequestVerificationToken` cookie if you submit it as `__RequestVerificationToken` in the form — you will need to parse the actual value from the form returned by `https://paydirect.link2gov.com/NYCParking-Plate/ItemSearch`. Your form data also does not follow the actual input fields in the original form — you have omitted some of them, and you're passing `ItemSearchQuestionUserInput` instead of `ItemSearchQuestionUserInput[0].QuestionAnswer`. Another thing is that you're actually supplying the *response* headers received from the first request as *request* headers of the second, which doesn't make much sense — those two contexts are not interchangeable like you assume.

I've modified your code to the point that I receive a "We couldn't find any matches. Please check your input and try again." message, which I also get when submitting the form in an browser — I don't have an actual US license plate to test with. Note that I've introduced an additional dependency on the [`lxml` module](http://lxml.de/) for parsing the form returned by the first request.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import requests
import urllib
from lxml import etree

session = requests.Session()
session.headers.update({'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.131 Safari/537.36'})

tokenRequest = session.get('https://paydirect.link2gov.com/NYCParking-Plate/ItemSearch')

parser = etree.HTMLParser()
tree = etree.fromstring(tokenRequest.text, parser)
verificationToken = tree.xpath('//form//input[@name="__RequestVerificationToken"]/@value')[0]

sessionCookies = tokenRequest.cookies

payload = {
    '__RequestVerificationToken': verificationToken,
    'ItemSearchQuestionUserInput[0].QuestionAnswer': 'myplate',
    'Questions[0].IsRequired': 'True',
    'Questions[0].Options': '',
    'Questions[0].DefaultAnswer': '',
    'Questions[0].Sequence': 1,
    'Questions[0].Text': 'PlateNumber',
    'Questions[0].Type': 'Text',
    'ItemSearchQuestionUserInput[1].QuestionAnswer': 'NY',
    'Questions[1].IsRequired': 'True',
    'Questions[1].Options': '',
    'Questions[1].DefaultAnswer': '',
    'Questions[1].Sequence': 2,
    'Questions[1].Text': 'State',
    'Questions[1].Type': 'Text',
    'ItemSearchQuestionUserInput[2].QuestionAnswer': '',
    'Questions[2].IsRequired': 'False',
    'Questions[2].Options': '',
    'Questions[2].DefaultAnswer': '',
    'Questions[2].Sequence': 3,
    'Questions[2].Text': 'PlateType',
    'Questions[2].Type': 'Text',
    'SubmitButton': 'Continue'
}

raw = urllib.urlencode(payload)
headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
}
plateRequest = session.post('https://paydirect.link2gov.com/NYCParking-Plate/ItemSearch/Submit', data=raw, cookies=sessionCookies, headers=headers)

print plateRequest.text
```

Comment: perfect, thank you. will award the bounty when it allows me to :)

Comment: If you use `params` with a dictionary `requests` sends a `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` POST just fine.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Ah, that might be true. I just noticed it doesn't send the content type header with the code provided by OP.